# Moving 2 wordpress sites to one

Tags: import, export, xml

I am working on 2 different wordpress blogs into one new domain!
I used the Tools->Export to get the xml file and also chose the option to include files and attachments as I wanted to move all the articles with images. I did the same for the second site as well.

On the new site, when I try to import, it failed to do the complete import and it is not done properly. XML file is not even 10mb in size but still I changed the filesize and max size setting via php.ini to a higher number.

Can you please suggest a way to import both the sites into the new one? I am not sure if exporting and import .sql will help because there are chances of same post id or some common thing. How to carefully import images, users, contents etc from 2 sites into 1?

Please advise!

Comment: Did you receive an error message when you imported the XML file?

Comment: @RachelBaker on chrome I got the no data received message. but for one of the xml file the import was complete but it showed different messages like media file not imported, user not created so assigned the post to existing user etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the export tool but split the files using a tool like http://rangerpretzel.com/content/view/20/1/

You may need to check everything individually to make sure there's no conflicts like same name categories, tags and usernames.

Check posts, pages, comments, custom fields, terms, navigation menus and custom posts for potential conflicts.

You may want to set these up first manually and then import one category at a time if there's any conflicts.

You can also use the bulk edit feature to make changes if needed.

You may also have a problem with same name image file names which you will needed to change manually.

You might also want to change the site address and server path using a plugin like WP Migrate DB or similar which enables you to change links in the export file if you decide to export the database rather than use the export tool in WordPress.

Comment: Thank you, will try that. But to understand it better, cna I know if that xml file has the calls to image path, users etc as well? Because my understanding is that import takes time and also not proper is because it is trying to fetch the image (several images) one by one so if it is right then how splitting xml would help?

Comment: I would test it locally first in a demo site however i have updated my answer which includes another solution for exporting the database as another option.

Comment: There are various problems with the import even after splitting (just for one site I tried). It is not assigning the users to the posts properly ..it assigns to the main user on new site . It is tough to reassign as there are almost 500 articles.

Comment: I think you'll need to take it one step at a time and setup everything first before importing might work best based on my research.

Comment: Thanks you mean manually uploading images, create categories etc? linking the image back to the post will be a big hassle in this way. please advise if you have an idea to link images to the posts..

Comment: The linking shouldn't be a problem but creating terms, navigation menus, categories etc.

Comment: One last question - I did this, export and import posts, terms, users carefully and looks like it is all good. Now is there any way to get the images match the post and then export from old site to new site? I am assuming that as post title is already there, it should be somehow possible to match that and assign it as a featured image? please advise.